# RegEx - Match With Conditional Lookaround?

Tags: regex, conditional-statements, regex-lookarounds

i would like to match a part of the string using lookarounds, but only if other words are not contained in the line.

> Some bears live and eat in the woods.

in the above line, i'd like to find " eat in the " (between "live and" & "woods):

```
/(?<=\blive and\b).*?(?=\bwoods\b)/
```

but only if "bears" isn't apart of the line, either after, before or between the lookarounds.

other examples of lines that should not return a match are:

> Some animals live and eat in the
>   woods, like bears.
>
> Some animals live and eat bears in
>   the woods.

how can i add this condition to my regular expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is problematic because most flavors do not support a variable length look-behind, so you can't check the whole line. A simple approach is to match the whole line instead of using lookarounds:

```
^(?!.*\bbears\b).*?\blive and\b(.*?)\bwoods\b
```

Here, what previously was the whole match is the first capturing group. Depending on your you use it, it may make replacing this text a little less convenient.  Make sure to use the muliline flag (`/m`), and not the set the single-line flag (dot-all, or `/s`).

Working example: **http://rubular.com/r/TuADb2vB4w**

Note that the problem becomes very simple if you can solve it in two steps: filter out lines with `\bbears\b`, and match the wanted string.

Comment: it would certainly be more readable in two steps. that's good advice.  thanks.

Comment: tudor's answer works for the most part, but fails with multilines.  do you have any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 2):

In Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $a = "Some bears live and eat in the woods.";

#$a = "Some animals live and eat in the woods, like bears.";

$a = "Some animals live and eat bears in the woods.";

$a =~ /(?(?!.*bears.*)(.*\blive and\b(.*)\bwoods\b.*)|(.{0}))/g;

print $2;
```

The condition `?(?!.*bears.*)` is like

```
if the string contains the bears string
   then matches .*\blive and\b(.*)\bwoods\b.*
   else matches .{0}
```

Youd don't need lookarounds to match between `live and` and `woods`

Read more about [Regex Conditionals here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html)

Comment: thanks!  this works great!  it appears that the else is optional (at least in AS3), which looks like this:  myString.match(new RegExp("(?(?!.*\\bbears\\b.*)((?<=\\blive and\\b).*?(?=\\bwoods\\b)))", "g")));

Comment: humm. i may have jumped to conclusions here. this solution doesn't seem to work with multiple lines, even with the multiline flag set.  actual matching lines appearing after any lines with "bears" are disregarded.  any thoughts/advice?

Comment: how do you expect it to act on multuline strings?

Comment: to evaluate the condition on each line?  i'm not quite sure i follow your question.  "live and eat in woods\nbears live and eat in woods\nlive and sleep in woods" only returns " eat in " from the first line, but since the match fails on the second line as the word bears is present, it also fails for and returns nothing the third line, even though the third line should return " sleep in ".  in this case, i would like the array returned by matching lines to be (" eat in ", " sleep in "), but it's only (" eat in ",)

Answer (score 1):

Your question and the examples don't seem to match, but you can do something like:

```
(?!.*\bbears\b)(?<=\blive and\b).*?(?=\bwoods\b)
```

(just expanded your regex)

Comment: It misses cases where `bears` appears before the match. I don't think too many flavors support that kind of a look-behind, which is why I tried the whole-line approach. (.Net is an exception here, with something like `(?<!^(?=.*\bbears\b).*)`, but this question is probably using action-script)